Heads or Tails Survival
In a game with 100 people where every round every person picks heads or tails and a fair coin is flipped, every person who guesses wrong is eliminated. This continues with everyone guessing until there is only one person left. Assuming you know what everyone else guesses (everyone else picks randomly), you can gain an advantage by picking the less popular option.
How could you calculate how much this increases your odds of winning?
I tried to work this out using standard deviation and working out the average percentage of people that will get knocked out, but it became difficult and I believe my method only worked for the initial round with 100 people. I tried to simulate this in python and got an answer of about 0.0318 or 3.18 times better chance than randomly guessing. I was hoping someone could help me with a solution for this. Thanks

Interesting.  This is the same as if you are the only one guessing and, if you get it wrong you are eliminated and if you get it right we throw out at least half of the others (prob. twice distance from mean).  I expect it's simpler to look at it that way.

Setting it up that way at least provides a simple recursion.  Not seeing a path to a closed form solution at the moment.  Should say:  I am assuming that, if the others are evenly split, you just choose at random.  That's the only natural assumption, right?

@lulu Yep I think in that case you pick randomly. Yeah I think some recursion method may be necessary not sure what you mean by twice distance from the mean? Like two standard deviations? Is that because it doesn't matter if heads or tails

No, consider the even case: I am playing against $N=2k$ people.  Then if I win we eliminate $i$ people where $k≤i≤N$ and the probability that we choose exactly $i$ is $\binom Nk \times \frac 1{2^N}$ if $i=k$ and it's $2\times \binom Ni \times \frac 1{2^N}$ if $i>k$, with a similar formula if $N$ is odd.

It looks as if it may be about a $0.0461$ probability of winning overall for the contrarian, substantially higher than for the pure guessers.  But if the contrarian is eliminated  then there is a positive probability of nobody winning, e.g. if the last group of pure guessers are eliminated together.

@cherrytree Given that the game lasts $R$ rounds, the probability of winning is $(1/2)^R$, but the unconditional probability of winning $E( (1/2)^R) \neq (1/2)^{(E(R))}$ in general.

Let $p(n)$ be the probability of winning the game with $n$ players. Consider the first round, and let $Z$ be the number of opponents choosing the less popular option. Then $Z \stackrel{d}{=} \min(X, n-X)$, where $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,1/2)$ is the number of opponents choosing heads. In particular, when $n$ is odd
$$P(Z = k) = P(X = k) + P(X = n-k) = 2 \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{2^n}$$
for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. By conditioning on $Z$,
$$p(n) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} p(k)$$
where $p(0) = 1$ and $p(1) = 1/2$. When $n$ is even, the recursion is
$$p(n) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1} \binom{n}{k} p(k) + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \binom{n}{n/2} p(n/2)$$
This is a relatively simple recursion that can be coded in R
n <- 100
p <- rep(1, n)
p[1] <- 0.5
p[2] <- 3/8

for(i in 3:n) {
  n2 <- floor(i/2)
  if(i %% 2 == 0) {
    n2 <- n2 - 1
    p[i] <- (1 + sum(choose(i,1:n2)*p[1:n2]))/2^i + p[i/2]*choose(i,i/2)/2^{i+1}
  } else {
    p[i] <- (1 + sum(choose(i,1:n2)*p[1:n2]))/2^i 
  }
}

In particular, I get $p(100) = 0.02$, which is close to what you see in simulation.

Yeah, that's makes sense; thanks. I don't think I know enough about recursion to recreate this solution myself, but it's interesting that it slightly more than doubles your odds of winning. (I also found an error in my code that I was not including myself in the number of players.) Now, I also get very slightly over 0.02.
